# Porting python code to C++ / (Printing out arrays in c++)

Tags: python, c++

I am currently learning C++ and being quite proficient in python, I decided to try porting some of my python code to C++. Specifically I tried porting this generator I wrote that gives the fibonacci sequence up to a certain given stop value.

```
def yieldFib(stop):
    a = 0
    b = 1
        yield i
    for i in range(2):
    for i in range(stop-2):
        fib = a+b
        a = b
        b = fib
        yield fib
fib = list(yieldFib(100))
print(fib)
```

to this

```
int* fib(int stopp){
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int fibN;
    int fibb[10000000];
    fibb[0] = 0;
    fibb[1] = 1;
    for(int i=2; i<stopp-2; i++){
        fibN = a+b;
        a =  b;
        b =  fibN;
        fibb[i] = fibN;
    }
    return fibb;
}
int main(){
    int stop;
    cin >> stop;
    int* fibbb = fib(stop);
    cout << fibbb;
}
```

I admit the c++ is very crude, but this is just to aid my learning. for some reason the code just crashes and quits after it takes user input, I suspect it has something to do with the way i try to use the array, but I'm not quite sure what. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, you never assign a value to `fibN` in your function to begin with. To use it you need to give it a value. Another thing, what is `b` use for, you don't use it in your function anywhere.

Comment: `int fibb[10000000];` is probably too large for the stack. You might consider `std::vector<int>` instead. You should also be aware of the range of values an `int` can hold. You'll pass that limit very quickly.

Comment: @bluejambo my error, i accidently copied the wrong code to SO, i have corrected it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An integer array of size 10000000 is generally too large to be allocated on the stack, which causes the crash. Instead, use a `std::vector<int>`. In addition to that:

- The variable `b` is unused.
- `fibN` is not initialized. Its value will be indeterminate.
- Returning a pointer to stack memory will not work, as that pointer is no longer valid once the function has returned.
- The code would print the value of an *integer pointer* instead of the values of the array. Instead, iterate over the array and print the values one by one.

On a side note: It seems that you are trying to learn C++ by trial-and-error, while it is best learned from the ground up using a book or course.

Comment: Hey, thank. I have corrected fibN, accidentally copied an older version of the code for the example. Also, I am following a course actually but not fully done. I wrongfully assumed I had enough knowledge to start trying out some things I guess.

Answer (score 0):

In provided code, I see many mistakes.

First: You're creating int-array with 10000000 length inside stack (you're not allocating memory) what is 40 MB! You just exceed the stack length (1 MB, as I remember). Just allocate it with new operator. If you don't want to work with this kind of array (or don't want to calculate its precise length), you can use std::vector which can expand himself in memory.

```
int* fibb = new int[precise_length];
//or
std::vector<int> fibb = std::vector<int>(); //and fill it by calling fibb.push_back()
```

Second: cout usage. You try to print array POINTER, not contents. Print every member of array separately.

Comment: wow, thanks. this was extremely insightful. so it means "arrays/lists" are actually pointers in c++ and can't be printed out at a go like regular python

Comment: Would be nice to notice: this is not Python where you don't see the memory background. Here you should manage the memory by yourself and count every byte you use. If you allocate something ("new" operator), you should(!) deallocate it when it'll be unnecessary to avoid memory leaks. Variables which are created in stack (without new, just as you created that massive array), shouldn't be deallocated with delete operator.

Comment: @TochiBedford, Yes, that's right. I would recommend, as Yun said above, to read about memory managing to understand how things are contained there. Then C++ will be very easy for you :)